# Sidekiq working from console but not working from app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq, linode

When I run sidekiq from rails console

`ActivationWorker.perform_async(832181)`

it works fine, but when I do hit from app nothing executes and not a get any logs also in `log/sidekiq.log`

Comment: Did you start the Sidekiq process?

Comment: @MikePerham yes its running

Comment: otherwise it cant run on console

Comment: The console is the client, pushing the job to Redis.  The job won't execute unless you are running a server process with `bundle exec sidekiq`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rails console in production mode so that the environments are different?  The configs might be different between dev and prod.
2. You see workers listening in sidekiq admin?
3. You can inspect the `sidekiq_options` to help debug.  I don't have a shell but if you can rails console in, try inspecting your ActivationWorker and see if you have that hash of options.  Maybe it's pushing somewhere weird that workers aren't seeing?

No logs means it's going to stdout.  You can specify a file with `-L`.
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging